# es6でclassを定義したとき、eslint（no-shadow: 2）を通らない理由を知りたい

Tags: javascript, eslint

babelを使用してes6でjsを書いています。
linterをjsxhintからeslintへ変更し、.eslintrcのno-shadowを2にしてチェックしたのですが、以下のような注意がでます。

```
CLASS is alrerady declared in the upper scope. (no-shadow)
```

※ CLASSは定義したclass名です
no-shadowを0にすれば出なくなるのは良いのですが、なぜこのようなエラーがでるのか理由を知りたく質問させていただきました。対処法があれば教えていただければ幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

非常にシンプルではありますがclassの例を記述します（これでも同じエラーが出ることを確認済）。

```
class Something {
  constructor() {
    // do something
  }
}
```

.eslintrcは[airbnb/javascript](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/blob/master/linters/.eslintrc)で再現可能かと思います。

Comment: Babelとeslintのサイトで簡単なクラス定義を試したところでは再現できなかったのですが、エラーを再現できるclass定義の例を書いていただけないでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。
内容編集で追記いたしました。不明点・不足などあれば遠慮なくお願いします。

Comment: なるほど、Babelで変換したものをeslintに通した時は問題なかったのですが、eslint+babel-eslintに直接通すとそのエラーが確認できました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ちょうど**今日**、バグ報告されたようです。

[Latest release 0.21.1 fails with ES6 classes and babel-eslint · Issue #2545 · eslint/eslint](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/2545)

とりあえずの回避策としては eslint のバージョンを 0.21.0 に落とせばいいとのこと。

Comment: そうでしたか！
Issueを見逃すとは...申し訳ない。ありがとうございます！
またeslint@0.21.0で行ったところ、問題なく動きました。
ありがとうございます！